# How can i test the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, clipboard

I have this function to copy the current url to the clipboard.

```
const copyToClipboard = (str) => {
  const tmpElm = document.createElement('textarea');
  tmpElm.value = window.location.href;
  tmpElm.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  tmpElm.style.position = 'absolute';
  tmpElm.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(tmpElm);
  tmpElm.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(tmpElm);
};
```

How exactly can I test this function? (using a test framework like jest, which is not nested in a browser).

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest test you can do is stub your `execComand` fn

```
document.execCommand = jest.fn();
```

then you can write a test like

```
expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith("copy");
```